# jQuery modals and deep linking

Tags: jquery

I currently have a gallery which opens a modal pop up when you click on the thumbnail. What I would like to do is to be able to generate a unique link specifically for the modal (i.e.; www.mywebite.com/#link1), which loads it's content via ajax. If somebody was to send this unique modal link and send it to someone and they were to paste it into their browser, ideally I would like the modal window to load and display its content automatically, without the user having to click on the appropriate thumbnail.

Is this even possible?? I know this is not the easiest of tasks and any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

To get an idea of what I'm working on go to:
http://www.ddbremedy.co.uk/siteupdate/work

You will see an iMac screen with the thumbnails on it.

Many thanks in advance.

UPDATE!!!!!

Ok this is where I am currently at. I have decided to scrap using jquery address and am deep linking using 'window.location.hash' instead.

Code is something like this:

```
var base_url = "http://www.ddbremedy.co.uk/siteupdate/";

$('#work_gallery li a').on('click', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    postLink = $(this).attr('href');
    window.location.hash = postLink.replace(base_url, "");


    /* I have a bunch of code that animates the modal window 
    in which I don't need to include as there is quite alot of it.
    Content loads via ajax. Then when I close the modal I add this 
    code to remove the hash and revert the link back to its original state. */

    if ("pushState" in history) {
        history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);
    } else {
        window.location.hash = "";
    }

});
```

The above code works fine and displays the link exactly as I want it to when I load and close external content with ajax. Now what I need to figure out is how I can automatically load the ajax content if somebody takes that link and pastes it in the address bar.  The content is loaded based on the links href and a click event, so how would I trick the browser into thinking that the correct link was clicked and load the correct content, purely based on it's link?

Comment: I think these might help you. http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/ and https://github.com/balupton/History.js

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I'm already using jQuery address to create the deep-link, which I can seem to get working. The problem is pasting that url back into a separate window and getting the modal to activate.

Comment: You should post your code then :) I will be out till tomorrow but if someone here haven't helped you out I can certainly get back to you tomorrow. If you have address setup already, it will most probably be a matter of tweaking your code to make it work the way you want it.

Comment: Hello again, I have edited my initial question and added some code too. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to get it working. This is how I did it:

First I run a function called 'checkUrl' which checks the URL to see if it contains a hash.

```
checkUrl = function() {
    if (window.location.hash) {

    }
};

checkUrl();
```

Then within the if statement I store the hash path into variable and split it from the hash. I then store the string after the hash into a variable.

```
var pathname = window.location.hash,
    rez = pathname.split('#'),
    linkUrl = rez[1];
```

I then pass that variable as a selector for the link that has that particular href and trigger a click event on the corresponding link, which then animates and loads in the correct modal.

```
$("a[href='http://www.ddbremedy.co.uk/siteupdate/" + linkUrl + "']").trigger('click');
```

Hopefully this will help someone in the future.

Comment: It work well! great job. I follow your method for this photo website http://journal.tumultes.net/les-iles-traversees/

Answer (score 1):

This is completely possible. Semi-pseudocode using [jquery simplemodal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    /* Get the hash from window.location */
    var theHash = window.location.hash;
    if (theHash !== '') 
    {
        /* Load something related to it */
        $.get(something-from-somewhere, function(data) {
           /* Open the simplemodal and put the returned data inside it */
           $.modal(data);
        });
    }
});
```

Obviously there's loads more you can do with the modal, which you'll find in [the documentation](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/#overview).