# Angularjs deep linking to visual content (like modals)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My application has several 'modal' windows, For now there is no specific route to reach an open modal directly.  I mean, written the url directly in the browser.

There are a [Jquery solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15573893/jquery-modals-and-deep-linking), but how implement some similar solution for angular? where placed? when should run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform this sort of task within the routing config of your app.

For example, this one is using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), for the routes, and [ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) for the modals.

In the route config add an `onEnter` which will fire when the route is first entered.

```
   .state('login', {
        onEnter: function ($stateParams, $state, $modal) {
            $modal.open({
                keyboard: false, // prevents escape-key closing modal
                backdrop: 'static', // prevents closing modal outside of the modal
                templateUrl: '/views/login', // view to load
                controller: 'LoginCtrl' // controller to handle
            })
        }
    })
```

Now, when navigating to the, in this example, `login` page the route will open the modal for me.